# Determine an angle in two overlapping triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-algorithm

A triangle $ABC$ is given as shown below. We know that $i = i_1$ and $k = k_1 = k_2$. Determine angle $\gamma$ $geometrically$. Note: Through variations in 'geogebra' I think that $\gamma = \frac{3}{4} \pi $ (or 135°). But how prove it? Does knowing $tan(\alpha)= \frac{k}{i+k} ,$ and $ tan(\beta)=\frac{i}{i+2k} $ help?  [image]

Comment: Try the angle sum formula for the tangent. Note that $\gamma = \pi - (\alpha + \beta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the two unnamed bottom points by $D$ and $E$, as in the picture. Let $\omega$ be the circle with diameter $DR$ and $\Omega$ be the circle with diameter $DB$. Let $C'\neq D$ be the second intersection point of $\omega$ and $\Omega$.

Note that $\angle RC'D = 90^\circ = \angle DC'B$, hence $C'$ lies on $RB$.

Also note that $\angle AC'D = \angle ARD = 45^\circ$ and $\angle DC'S = \angle DC'B + \angle BC'S = 90^\circ + \frac 12 \angle BES = 90^\circ + 45^\circ = 135^\circ$. Therefore $\angle AC'D + \angle DC'S = 180^\circ$, hence $C'$ lies on $AS$.

This shows that $C'$ is the intersection of $BR$ and $AS$, hence $C'=C$. To finish, note that $\angle ACB = \angle ACD + \angle DCB = 45^\circ+90^\circ = 135^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: Just a question: Why is angle AC'D = 45°? It must be obvious but I can't see it. Thanks.

Comment: $\angle AC'D=\angle ARD$ because the angles subtend the same arc $AD$. The fact that $\angle ARD=45^\circ$ follows from the fact that triangle $ARD$ is right and isosceles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, having remarked that $\tan(\alpha)= \frac{k}{i+k}$ and $\tan(\beta)= \frac{i}{i+2k}$ is very useful because :

$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}{1-\tan \alpha \tan\beta}=\frac{\frac{k}{i+k}+\frac{i}{i+2k}}{1-\frac{k}{i+k}\frac{i}{i+2k}}=\frac{i^2+2ik+2k^2}{i^2+2ik+2k^2}=1 \ \text{const.}$$

Therefore, using the fact that the sum of angles in triangle $ABC$ is equal to $\pi$, we have:

$$\tan \gamma = \underbrace{\tan(\pi-(\alpha+\beta))}_{-\tan(\alpha+\beta)} = -1.$$

... a constant... **which is indeed equal to $\tan(\underbrace{3 \pi/4)}_{135°}=-1$.

(As a consequence, $C$ belongs to an arc of circle passing through $A$ and $B$ subtanding angle $135°$).

Comment: The equality $\frac{\frac{k}{i+k}+\frac{i}{i+2k}}{1-\frac{k}{i+k}\frac{i}{i+2k}}=\frac{i(2i+3k)}{k(2i+3k)}$ doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @timon92 Thanks. Now corrected. Where I had my head ?

Comment: I think it is still incorrect. The expression should simplify to $1$.

Comment: @timon92 Now, I think it is correct. Apologies... and thanks...